# How to use allowed_domains with relative paths?

Tags: scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and want to build a simple web crawler. Unfortunately, if I'm using a allowed_domain, scrapy filters out all subpages as the domain is using relative path. How can this be fixed?

```
class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "example_crawler"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.example.com"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(),
             callback="parse_text",
             follow=True),)

    def parse_text(self, response):
        pass
```

If I remove the allowed_domains all subpages are crawled. However, if I'm using a allowed domain all subpages are getting filtered because of the relative path issue. Can this be solved?

Comment: `allowed_domains` should work the same with absolute URLs and relative URLs. The next request should receive the absolute URL, otherwise it cannot be fetched anyway. Something else must be the issue. Can you gather and post more details on what the URLs look like and maybe an excerpt from the output of the crawl (in `DEBUG` mode, so that it shows which requests it sends and what gets filtered out).

Comment: @Aufziehvogel thanks for your comment. How can I set debug mode? Im running my crawl spider on the terminal via `scrapy runspider`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allowed domains should not contain `www.` and such.

If you take a look at `OffsiteMiddleware` it renders all values in allowed_domains to regex and then matches every page you try to crawl to this regegular expression:

```
    regex = r'^(.*\.)?(%s)$' % '|'.join(re.escape(d) for d in allowed_domains if d is not None)
    return re.compile(regex)
```

Regular expression allows subdomains so you can easily have `allowed_domains=['example.com', 'foo.example.com']`. If you leave in `www.` scrapy thinks it's a subdomain thus it will fail on urls that do not have it.

Comment: many thanks for your help. My url is of the form: `example.com/global/en/home`. Now I want everything starting with this. Can this be achieved? Removing the `www` didnt help

Comment: That's not the purpose of `allowed_domains` - it's for restricting domains. For your purpose you need to define proper rules in your rules. See `allowed` argument in `LinkExtractor`: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html?highlight=allow#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml